# There is a problem with the code, I can not find a solution

Tags: python, heroku

```
There is a problem with the code, I can not find a solution

C:\Users\sphe\justeat>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 61, done.
Counting objects: 100% (61/61), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (61/61), 1015.17 KiB | 647.00 KIS/s, done.
Total 61 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:Requested runtime (python-3.5.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.co...
remote: ! Push failed
```

remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: ! Push rejected to enigmatic-spire-63168.
    To https://git.heroku.com/enigm...
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/enigm...

Comment: The error message gives you a clue of what's wrong - `:Requested runtime (python-3.5.2) is not available for this stack...` (missing python version) and the next line beginning with `More info...` explains in more detail .Have you visited that link?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title to the issue so users will find and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Your Problem

remote:Requested runtime (python-3.5.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)

## Solution:

by the official website of [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), your python version (3.5.2) isn't compatible with heroku version 18.

#### From Developer Webpage:

> ### Specifying a Python version
>
> By default, newly created Python apps use the python-3.6.8 runtime. **[You can also specify a different supported Python version.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)**
>
> #### Supported runtimes
>
> - python-3.7.3 on all (heroku-16, and heroku-18) runtime stacks
> - python-3.6.8 on all (heroku-16, and heroku-18) runtime stacks
> - python-2.7.16 on all (heroku-16, and heroku-18) runtime stacks